# Allow access to computed duration in jquery time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using two separate timepickers to compute a time duration which works out well for the user. however, i also want to have access to the duration -- which I would like to use in a calculation late on the page. my question is -- how can i access the duration which has already been computed and is displayed to the user upon use of the second timepicker?

I am using this jquery timepicker: https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery

my html

```
<div class = "form-group">
    <label for="lesson_start_time">Lesson start time:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lesson_start_time" name="lesson_start_time" class="form-control ui-timepicker-input">
</div>
<div class = "form-group" id="end_time">
    <label for="lesson_end_time">Lesson end time:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lesson_end_time" name="lesson_end_time" class="form-control ui-timepicker-duration">
</div>
```

my js

```
// for start time of lesson
$('#lesson_start_time').timepicker({ 'step': 15 });
// temporarily disable end time
$("#lesson_end_time").prop('disabled', true);
// when a start time is chosen
$('#lesson_start_time').on('changeTime', function() {
    // enable the end time input
    $('#lesson_end_time').prop('disabled', false);
    // enable the input as a timepicker
    $('#lesson_end_time').timepicker({
        'minTime': $(this).val(),
        'showDuration': true,
        'step':15
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this plugin doesn't provide requested functionality. You can post a feature request at [Github](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/issues/new) for it.

But there is a workaround: you can use actual value of the selected duration by finding appropriate `span` and get it's `text()`.

HTML that is generated for `timepicker` is:

```
<div class="ui-timepicker-wrapper ui-timepicker-with-duration">
    <ul class="ui-timepicker-list">
        <li>12:15am<span class="ui-timepicker-duration"> (15 mins)</span></li>
        <li class="ui-timepicker-selected">1:00am<span class="ui-timepicker-duration"> (1 hr)</span></li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

We can use it in following way:

1. When creating `timepicker` for `lesson_end_time`, add `className:
   'endTime'` option:

   ```
   $('#lesson_end_time').timepicker({
       /*...*/
       className: 'endTime'
       /*...*/ });
   ```

   This class will be added to the topmost `div`, so, it will become:

   `<div class="ui-timepicker-wrapper endTime
   ui-timepicker-with-duration">`
2. Inside `changeTime` handler find needed `span` in this way:

   ```
   var selectedDurationSpan = $(".ui-timepicker-wrapper.endTime").find("li.ui-timepicker-selected").find("span.ui-timepicker-duration");
   ```
3. Then we can get it's value. It will be in parenteses and with spaces (**" (30 mins)"**), we can purify it ro become **"30 mins"**:

   ```
   var selectedDuration = selectedDurationSpan.text().trim().replace(/[()]/g,'');
   ```

   Value could be applied to some `input`, (i have created `<input id='lesson_duration' />`):

   ```
   $("#lesson_duration").val(selectedDuration);
   ```

So, here is full code for `lesson_end_time` timepicker initialization:

```
$('#lesson_end_time').timepicker({
    minTime: $(this).val(),
    showDuration: true,
    step: 15,
    className: 'endTime'
}).on("changeTime", function () {
    var selectedDurationSpan = $(".ui-timepicker-wrapper.endTime").find("li.ui-timepicker-selected").find("span.ui-timepicker-duration");
    var selectedDuration = selectedDurationSpan.text().replace(/[()]/g, '');
    $("#lesson_duration").val(selectedDuration);
});
```

## Full demo is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/3wNLU/)

Answer (score 2):

it can be computed this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/4fqU8/1/

```
$(function(){
$('input.time').timepicker();
$('#delta').on('click', function(){
    var seconds = $('#time2').timepicker('getSecondsFromMidnight') - $('#time1').timepicker('getSecondsFromMidnight');

    // compensate for negative values;
    if (seconds < 0) {
        seconds += 86400;
    }

    alert((seconds / 60) + ' minutes');
});
});
```

from:

https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker/issues/191